# Change repo url in TortoiseGit

Tags: tortoisegit

We just updated our git repos to a new location and I'm using TortoiseGit with some uncommited changes.  Can I change the folder reference anywhere?  I'm not seeing the option in the context menus.  I'd rather not recreate and merge if avoidable since there are about 14 repos in total.  I'm not well versed in git so please let me know if the question is flawed as well.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

As far as i understand question. Path to change url of remote repository is:

- Right click on main folder
- TortoiseGit
- Settings
- Git
- Remote
- Select the remote to update in the list of remotes
- In field remote select origin -> url of repository will appear in field URL: and can be changed from here.

Uncommited changes can be stashed, or committed locally.

Comment: wow, just now saw this had been answered.  Apologies on the late response.

Comment: Similar way: you can do it from TortoiseGit/Push,
than "Manage" button in "Destination (remote)",
than edit origin URL as in StormRideR's answer.

Comment: I had to change "Language" to "English" in "Settings → General → TortoiseGit" in order to find "Remote".