# GitHub Fork and History in Pull Requests out of Sync

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

I have a fork and a upstream/master.

The fork and upstream are in sync change wise, but when I do a Pull Request from the fork, the all the changes from when the Fork was created are in the request plus the new changes.  This is annoying and hard to figure out what was changed/important to review.

How can I stop my PR from looking like a bunch of verbal diarrhea in a pull request?
Is there away to force the fork to sync with the upstream/master's history?

I am using TortoiseGit to manage the repositories.

Comment: Can you supply a link to such PR (if public, otherwise create a minimal example artificially) to show what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Before seding your branch to yourfork on GitHub, you are supposed to rebase it (replay its commits) against the upstream branch from the origina repo.

So if you are making a PR branch from master, you would need to:

- [add an upstream remote referencing the original repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17901695/6309) (settings/git/remotes in TortoiseGit)
- [fetch from the remote](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-pull.html)
- then [rebase your current PR branch on top of `upstream/master`](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-rebase.html)

Now you can [push (or force push if you did already push)](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html): the PR will be updated, and will include only new changes.

Comment: so I did 1 and 2 already, but when I go to rebase, it keeps telling me there are conflicts, what is the exact command for the rebase that I should use?

Comment: @codebase5000 conflicts are expected if your PR is modifying the same files that have been updated upstream (in the original repo): you need to resolve those conflicts: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-conflicts.html.